# how to convert mysql enum to postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.3

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
 id int NOT NULL,
  firstname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  lastname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  username varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  phone varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  address text NOT NULL,
  type enum('admin','employee') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'employee'
);
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html

Comment: Are you really using Postgres 9.3? It is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). If you start a new project today, you should use the latest version (which is 11)

Comment: I am using 9.3, I will use the latest version now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enums are not really a good way to model. In Postgres better alternatives exists, e.g. check constraints or foreign keys.

But if you do want to de-normalize your model (which is what enums do), you need to first define an enum type:

```
CREATE TYPE emp_type AS ENUM ('admin','employee');

CREATE TABLE employees 
(
   id int NOT NULL,
   firstname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   lastname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   username varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   password varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   phone varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   address text NOT NULL,
   type emp_type NOT NULL DEFAULT 'employee'
);
```

Another option (which takes up a bit more space, but is more flexible) is to use a check constraint (which MySQL still doesn't support, and enums are a workaround for that):

```
CREATE TABLE employees 
(
   id int NOT NULL,
   firstname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   lastname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   username varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   password varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   phone varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   address text NOT NULL,
   type text  NOT NULL DEFAULT  'employee',
   check (type in ('employee', 'admin'))
);
```

---

Note that `type` is a SQL keyword (but not a reserved one). But in general it would be better to avoid using keywords as identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize DOMAIN CHECK

```
CREATE DOMAIN field AS TEXT
CHECK VALUE IN ('admin','employee');

Then you declare the table as:

CREATE TABLE employees (
    id int NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    phone varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    address text NOT NULL,
    jobType field
);
```

Comment: Tnx  but I got this ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VALUE"
LINE 51: CHECK VALUE IN ('admin','employee');

Comment: I suggest to read the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createdomain.html)